# A minimization problem be formulated as a simple semi-definite program.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

Consider the following block matrix:
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
\sqrt{t} \mathbb{I}_{d_{1}} & \dot{\tilde{K}}_{0}^{\dagger} & \dot{\tilde{K}}_{1}^{\dagger} & \ldots & \dot{\tilde{K}}_{k-1}^{\dagger} \\
\dot{\tilde{K}}_{0} & \sqrt{t} \mathbb{I}_{d_{2}} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\dot{\tilde{K}}_{1} & 0 & \sqrt{t} \mathbb{I}_{d_{2}} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dot{\tilde{K}}_{k-1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \sqrt{t} \mathbb{I}_{d_{2}}
\end{array}\right),
$$
where $\dot{K_i}^\dagger$ stands for a matrix and the dot stands for derivative respect to a parameter inside the matrix.

My question is why the requirement of the positive semi-definite of the matrix $A$ is equivalent to the condition:
$$
\alpha_{\tilde{K}}=\sum_{i} \dot{\tilde{K}}_{i}^{\dagger} \dot{\tilde{K}}_{i} \leq t \mathbb{I}_{d_{1}}.
$$
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This follows directly from a well-known result of Sylvester, which states that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same (multi-)set of nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: @user1551, sorry, I still don't get it. How should I construct the matrix $B$ you mentioned?

Comment: Your matrix is in the form of $\sqrt{t}I+ve_1^\ast+e_1v^\ast=\sqrt{t}I+\pmatrix{v&e_1}\pmatrix{e_1&v}^\ast$.